# "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point WindowsFormsApp" Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms

I am trying to make a form application but when I run it I get an error like this

**"Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point  WindowsFormsApp"**.

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a file called program.cs? Should be located in you project. In there should be a function called main do you have that?

Comment: That means what it says.  You must have a `Main` method that is declared `static`.  It's the entry point (first method ran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Main` method is the `entry point` of a C# application. (Libraries and services do not require a Main method as an entry point.) When the application is started, the Main method is the first method that is invoked.
When this `Main` method is not present it will give the error you have now.

The program.cs should look something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>


   [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
}
```

Please see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/)

Comment: I understand.Thanks!

Comment: @ByKizmaz No problem, Happy coding!